# Calculate using Semantic MediaWiki and Expressions

Tags: properties, mediawiki, semantics, semantic-mediawiki

I'm working on a SMW environment at [Enipedia](http://enipedia.tudelft.nl). We created Forms and Templates to input and show properties. I'm trying to do a simple calculation, with three properties from the same template that is featured on the page itself. It  has this shape: new property = prop1 / (prop2 * (prop3/100)).

I'm trying to use {{#expr to evaluate the expression, but it doesn't retrieve the numbers from the properties for calculation. This is demonstrated by using:
    {{#if:{{{Investment Cost}}} {{{Cycle Durability}}} {{{Roundtrip Efficiency}}} | this is where we calculate: {{#expr:{{{Cycle Durability}}} * 10 }} | '''(not all required properties are given)''' }}.

This example can be found on [here](http://enipedia.tudelft.nl/wiki/Generic_LiFePo_battery). My questions are:

1. How do I retrieve SMW properties to use in Expressions?
2. How do I calculate using these properties?

Comment: This question is confusing properties with template parameters. Which of the two you want to use?